# Execute python file with node.js

Tags: python, node.js, web, hosting, sympy

I want to make a website where the user types in a mathematical expression and the node server calculates the expression using `python-shell` and `Sympy`. My code looks like this

```
app.post('/calculate_sympy', (req, res) => {
    let data = req.body.expression;

    PythonShell.runString(`from sympy import *;from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr; print(latex(parse_expr("${data}")))`, null).then(messages=>{
        res.send(messages[0])
    });
})
```

on the localhost it runs perfectly but when I uploaded it to cyclic (hosting platform) it throws an error

```
2023-07-22 19:44:34.503: node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn python3 ENOENT
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
Emitted 'error' event on PythonShell instance at:
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:180:18)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:289:12)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn python3',
  path: 'python3',
  spawnargs: [ '/tmp/pythonShellFile3744318054.py' ]
}
2023-07-22 19:44:34.503: 
Node.js v18.16.1
```

Why is it throwing that error and how to resolve it? Thanks in advance.

I already copied the `python3` file into my directory and linked the code with it but it still does not work.

Comment: i will be interested to see an answer for this...   i believe that if i was going to run a script in a different language, that i would invoke it from a command line comment.